# swift: add custom UIView above the TabCOntroller that appress on all views

Tags: swift

Is there a way to place a UIView above the tab navigation bar that will appear  on all views?

I would like a custom view placed on top of the tab navigation show that it will appear on all view.  The custom UI view will have a label in it to display content.

Comment: You have two options: either implement a custom Container view controller ([see this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW12)) or in the storyboard add a container view, and on top of that container add the label

Comment: I don't use the storyboard. I am doing all this in code.  where would I add this custom UI? Which controller?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: I got it to work. But not sure if I am choosing the correct anchor point.  I used the view bottom as the anchor point. Would be nice to use the nabbar item container as the anchor point.

Comment: The another approach load custom view code in BaseClass and inherit in all your subclass.